# Kendo Grid MVC Server Side wrappers with Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I setup Kendo Grid along with MVC server side wrapper using Web API. Here is my code in view

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.UserViewModel>()
          .Name("UserGrid")
          .Columns(column =>
          {
              column.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
              column.Bound(c => c.LastName);
              column.Bound(c => c.Email);
          })
          .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Model(m => m.Id(u => u.Id))
                .Read(read => read.Url("/api/..").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))

          )
    )
```

Here is my web api controller and the problem which I found it is I am getting null is request parameter. I am not sure why it is happening, any suggestionj please

```
public DataSourceResult GetAllUsers
            ([ModelBinder(typeof(DataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var users= _userRepository.GetAllUsers();
            return users.ToDataSourceResult(request, s => new UserViewModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                FirstName = s.FirstName,
                LastName = s.LastName,
                Email = s.Email

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to allow get on your controller method:

```
public DataSourceResult GetAllUsers
            ([ModelBinder(typeof(DataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var users= _userRepository.GetAllUsers();
            return users.ToDataSourceResult(request, s => new UserViewModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                FirstName = s.FirstName,
                LastName = s.LastName,
                Email = s.Email

            }).JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        }
```